# RxSwift : How to autoresize sublayer with view's resizing

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm learning RxSwift.

I added a border as CALayer to TextField. I would like to make this border reactively auto-resized as the textField is expanded (inputView changed to pickerView so I wish it could be resized by selecting titles)

I tried `.rx.observe(CGRect.self, "frame")` but it doesn't work properly.

```swift
extension UITextField {

    func addBorderBottom(height: CGFloat, color: UIColor, width: CGFloat){
        let border = CALayer()
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height - height, width: width, height: height)
        border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    }

}
```

```swift
// viewContrller

func listDetailUISetup() {
        let yellowColor = UIColor.hex(string: "FFB500", alpha: 1)
        tagTextField.addBorderBottom(height: 1.0, color: yellowColor, width: tagTextField.frame.width)
}

//
picker.rx.modelSelected(String.self)
            .subscribe(onNext: { tags in
                self.tagTextField.text = tags[0]
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

tagTextField.rx.observe(CGRect.self, "frame")
            .subscribe(onNext: { frame in
                print("field frame changed")
                let layer = self.tagTextField.layer.sublayers![0]
                layer.frame = frame!
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

In a second way, I also tried to manually re-set a border after removing the previous one when a title in the pickerView is selected. But apparently, the width of the item selected at the previous time is reflected.

initial width

[image]

All's width

[image]

Favourite's width

[image]

```swift
icker.rx.modelSelected(String.self)
            .subscribe(onNext: { tags in
                self.tagTextField.text = tags[0]
                self.tagTextField.layer.sublayers = nil
                self.listDetailUISetup()
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Hopefully, you could help to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: But where do you resize `TextField`?

Comment: I wanted to resize CALayer added to sublayers of textField :(

Answer (score 1):

The `frame` property on a UIView is not KVO observable, so you can't observe it. The text field's `layoutSubviews` method is called whenever it changes size though so you can use that.

```
extension UIView {
    func addDynamicBorderBottom(height: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> Disposable {
        let border = CALayer()
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.height - height, width: frame.width, height: height)
        border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(border)

        return rx.methodInvoked(#selector(UIView.layoutSubviews))
            .bind(onNext: { [frame] _ in
                border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.height - height, width: frame.width, height: height)
            })
    }
}
```

But you would be better off making your border a UIView and setting up constraints to ensure it stays the right size.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I created a border as UIView anyway and set constraints.
Handling of CALayer is quite difficult for me. 
In terms of your solution, I haven't understood how to use your method in my code. Returning disposable means, is it considered to append after `modelSelected.subscribe`?